# Несмотря на то, что / то что

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли запятые?

- Я, несмотря на то(,) что она этого не хотела, принёс ей котёнка.
- Несмотря на то(,) что уже прошёл-таки год, мы-с всё ещё друзья, а не враги.
- Я сильно замучился, невзирая на то(,) что всего-то немного дел-то было.

Comment: во втором не нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы написала так:

(1) *Я, **несмотря на то что** она этого не хотела, принёс ей котёнка.*

Придаточное не расчленяется в середине главного.

(2) ***Несмотря на то что** уже прошёл-таки год, мы-с всё ещё друзья, а не враги.*

Начало предложения, придаточное нераспространенное.

(3)  *Я сильно замучился, **невзирая на то, что** всего-то немного дел-то было.*

Конец предложения, но придаточное распространенное, лучше его поделить на две части.

**Примеры** (нерасчлененный союз  "невзирая на то что"):

Сергей Романов. Парламент (2000)

*Пашут, **невзирая на то что** уже больше полугода не получают зарплату.*

Андрей Ростовский. По законам волчьей стаи (2000)

***Невзирая на то что** ты мне очень симпатична и даже чем-то запала в душу, связать свою жизнь с тобой я бы не смог.*

Comment: Я бы выбрал такую же пунктуацию.

Comment: Спасибо, Максим!

Answer (score 2):

В 1-м и 2-м примере возможны оба варианта.

***Я, несмотря на то что она этого не хотела, принёс ей котёнка.*** Здесь логическое ударение не падает на первую часть союза.

***Я, несмотря на тó, что она этого не хотела, принёс ей котёнка.*** Здесь логическое ударение падает на первую часть союза.

***Несмотря на то, что уже прошёл-таки год, мы-с всё ещё друзья, а не враги.*** Лог. удар. падает на 1-ую часть союза.

***Несмотря на то что уже прошёл-таки год, мы-с всё ещё друзья, а не враги.*** Не падает.

***Я сильно замучился, невзирая на то, что всего-то немного дел-то было.*** А здесь запятая нужна в любом случае, т. к. союз НЕВЗИРАЯ НА ТО, ЧТО расчленяется всегда. А союз НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО(,) ЧТО может расчленяться, а может не расчленяться.

Comment: Максим, а почему союз НЕВЗИРАЯ НА ТО, ЧТО расчленяется всегда? Есть такое правило? В литературе встречаются варианты с нерасчлененным союзом.

Comment: «Грамота.ру» так пишет.

Comment: Я посмотрела в Нацкорпусе, есть такие примеры,  Неясно, почему надо всегда расчленять. А ссылка у вас есть на Грамоту? Чем они обосновывают?

Comment: Ничем, как обычно. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_466

Comment: Спасибо. Может, это частотный вариант. Но я  бы не стала ориентироваться на обязательное расчленение, не вижу разницы между союзами.

Comment: @Sharon А почему _неясно_ с звглавной буквы?

Comment: Предложение у меня новое